# Removing root element array from the Response format in spring boot with Mongodb database

Tags: spring-boot, rest, aggregation-framework

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object getdetails(@RequestParam(value = "sample", required = false) String sample,
                         @RequestParam(value = "shipla", arequired = false) String shilpa,
                         @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) throws ParseException, JsonProcessingException, javax.xml.bind.ValidationException {

    Document docSourceSystem =new Document();
    List<Document> aggregate = new ArrayList<>();
    int queryLimit = 1000;
   
    if (sample != null && !sample.isEmpty())
        addCrtieria("sample","$Sample,indexCreated);
    if (shilpa != null && !shilpa.isEmpty())
        addCrtieria("shilpa",$Shilpa,indexCreated);
    if (name != null && !name.isEmpty())
        createTextIndexOrAddCriteria("name",Name,indexCreated);
  
    BasicDBObject sampleFields=new BasicDBObject();
    sampleFields.append("sample","$Sample);
    sampleFields.append("shilpa","$Shipla");
    sampleFields.append("name ","$Name");
   
    List<? extends Bson> pipeline=getAggregate(queryLimit, projectFields);
    
    List sampleList=collection.aggregate(pipeline).into(sampleAggregrate);

    return getPrettyDocument(claimsHS);
}
```

Response Fromat :

```
[
{
    "_id": "abcdefgh45c8ce639026",
    "sample": {
        "sample": "sample",
        "shilpa": "shilpa",
        "name": "",
        
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5ef646fec7c645c8ce63902e",
    "sample": {
        "sample": "sample",
        "shilpa": "shilpa",
        "name": "",
     
    }
},
```

]

Expecetd format :

```
{
    "_id": "abcdefgh45c8ce639026",
    "sample": {
        "sample": "sample",
        "shilpa": "shilpa",
        "name": "",
        
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5ef646fec7c645c8ce63902e",
    "sample": {
        "sample": "sample",
        "shilpa": "shilpa",
        "name": "",
     
    }
},
```

I am trying to remove the root element array[] from Response as it is creating an issue and want it in object format within {} braces . Array [] needs to removed from the response.Can anyone suggest how can be the Array [] is removed

Answer (score 0):

You method `return getPrettyDocument(claimsHS);` is returning a list of objects instead of a single object instance that is why jackson is converting it into json list notation. If you want it to be just an object , you need to return a single object instance from your controller.

If **your controller does not return more than two objects** as in your question, even though both these objects are of the same type if you really doesn't want it to be a List you can assign both these objects to a POJO class and return it.Make a simple POJO class and set both the objects to this class and then return that in response like :

```
class YourEnclosingPOJO {
  Object class1;
  Object class2;
  //write getter ,setters and constructors
}
```

then your json be like :

```
{
"class1":{
    "_id": "abcdefgh45c8ce639026",
    "sample": {
        "sample": "sample",
        "shilpa": "shilpa",
        "name": "",
        
    }
},
"class2":{
    "_id": "5ef646fec7c645c8ce63902e",
    "sample": {
        "sample": "sample",
        "shilpa": "shilpa",
        "name": "",
     
    }
}
}
```

**But if your controller is supposed to return multiple objects, that is the number may vary then keep it as List itself and handle it in your UI code.**